# Endless redirect loop when trying to redirect user to /en with navigator.language

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, redirect, userlocation

I've got a German Wordpress website (http://website.de) and made an English version of every page with TranslatePress (http://website.de/en). Now I tried to get the language of every user in JQuery with navigator.language and redirect not German-speaking users to /en:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        if (userLang == "de") {
            window.location = "http://www.website.de";;
        }
        else {
            window.location = "http://www.website.de/en";
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it results in an endless loop and the page is reloading every second. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: which page is this script on? The `/en` page, or the homepage - or both? The issue is essentially the same in all cases though, you need to only do the redirect if the user isn't already on the correct page - otherwise you will indeed get an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I inserted the script in the <head> of the wordpress page (with a function in an own plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robin Zigmond is correct - if you redirect in both the if and the else block, it will always result in an infinite loop (save for an exception). Maybe try

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
            var isUserOnEnglishVer = window.location.href.indexOf("website.de/en") >=0;
            if (userLang == "de" && isUserOnEnglishVer) {
                window.location = "http://www.website.de";
            }
            if (userLang != "de" && !isUserOnEnglishVer){
                window.location = "http://www.website.de/en";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

In other words, only redirect if you aren't on the correct version.

However, I would find it surprising if there isn't an in-built way for language redirects.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot @Ferenc!
There is an in-built way for language redirects in TranslatePress, but it requires the pro version.

Comment: Happy to help. Keep in mind this loses the path, so someone with a non German setup following a link to "http://www.website.de/path/to/your/resource" would end up on "http://www.website.de/en", which is detrimental to UX. 
Consider adding window.location.pathname to the redirect URI when DE -> EN, and the same without the first three characters ('/en') to when EN -> DE